# Responsive jquery carousel slider and lightbox

Tags: jquery, responsive-design, carousel, slide

I'm looking for a responsive carousel slider with lightbox window (responsive too).

- Carousel slider needs to be with thumbnails, and draggble to navigate to next/last slide.
- Needs to show more than 1 slide in the portview.
- Needs to be infinite (when you're in the last image, the next is the first, but without going to initial, have to be cycle).
- When click in a image, open a responsive lightbox window. It needs to resize (when screen resized) and be always in center of screen. The width and height are setted in %.

I search a lot in the internet and didn't find a complete solution with these requirements.

It can be free or pay.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Have you tried caroufredsel? It's free and pretty extensive.
[Link](http://caroufredsel.dev7studios.com/)